# Div 100% height in the center of the screen

Tags: css, html

To try to illustrate, I created the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/SUcmH/4/embedded/result/

- Yellow: This is the menu, is correct!
- Green: This is the footer, is correct! Must always be the bottom: 0 (or when the site is greater, must be pushed down!)
- Blue: Is the background of website! Is partially correct! It should take only the side of the site.
- Red: This is where will the contents of the site. It should go to the end of the site (without content)

> Something like height: 100% but below the footer!
>   
>   **Basically like that red occupies the entire center of the screen!**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, You'll need to set the height of .clearfooter and its parent (in this case #wrap) to a height of 100%

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhAKb/embedded/result/)**

```
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
}

.clearfooter {
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```